# Android studio, JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

I'm having this error when I try to register. Its very simple, when i click the register button, all the fields inputted are to be stored in a online database.
Now i used the same JSON code to login and it works fine, but i dont see what the problem is here. Iv even read that i need to maybe remove the echo in my php, but doing so i wont be able to tell if its true or false.

Any help? This is what keeps popping up in the console

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <br><table of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

This is my code, in the fragment.

```
bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String name = etName.getText().toString();
                final String surname = etSurname.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                final int phone = Integer.parseInt(etPhone.getText().toString());
                final int age = Integer.parseInt(etAge.getText().toString());

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
```

Its stopping here

```
                        try {
                            *****JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");*****

                            if(success){

                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), BlankFragment1.class);
                                BlankFragment2.this.startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); //create an error message
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null) //click retry to retry registration
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, surname,username,password,email,phone,age,responseListener);


                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
        return view;
```

This is what i have in my php code.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("mysql4.000webhost.com", "a3826656_user", "", "a3826656_data");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $surname = $_POST["surname"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, surname,  username, password, email, phone, age) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $surname, $username, $password, $email, $phone , $age);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);


    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error here

> JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
>                               boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

because the string response cannot be converted to json. I'm not entierly sure but I think it's because you are sending an array. Log the response in your console to be sure

Comment: that error is in the console, what should i do then, delete the response array?

Comment: Just before the try log out the response like Log.d("Activity Name", "Response is: " + response); and send me the screenshot of the log

Answer (score 0):

I thing the response format is the problem. If it is a valid JSON it definately do the parsing.check content type is json

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssssii", $name, $surname, $username, $password, $email, $phone , $age);
```

Make this change in your php code, it should work